# Angular 2 : Directives and providers in @component decorator

Tags: angular

Hi i am new to Angular 2, i referred many other similar post but nothing helped me.

Below are my Queries

1. When to use Directives and providers parameters in @component decorator? Do i need to pass component inside any of this parameters while i import component
2. I made a http subscribe call inside oninit() but it never's gets called when page loads I get undefined value in console. how do i call it when a page loads.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.getLoginData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.loginData = data;
        this.loginDataLength = data.length;
      });
      console.log(this.loginData);
  }
```

3. how do i communicate between 2 components while routing?
4. What is  the difference between Directive and Component

Comment: The `console.log()` call is executed before `this.loginData = data;` because `getLoginData()` is async.

Comment: @jay , if this answers your question , will you please accept the answer.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-- When to use Directives and providers parameters in @component decorator?**

Directives , when you want to use directives , you can load those inside that , but that was in older version.

Providers ,  when you want to load services in your components or modules

**-- First of all change your code to this :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.getLoginData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.loginData = data;
        this.loginDataLength = data.length;
        console.log(this.loginData);
      });
      
  }
```

This is async call , so you will not get data in sequence , your console log will not called after http call finishes , it will be called as soon as the api called, so you have to log that inside subscribe method.

**-- how do i communicate between 2 components while routing?**

By using CommonService and provide it at route level or as per the project structure and your requirements.

Comment: Just to add , use constructor instead onInit. cause, sometimes it works asynchronously.

Comment: Angular 2 , itself suggests use ngOnInit instead of constructor as much as possible.

Comment: Do i need to pass component inside any of this Directives and providers parameters while i import component inside another component

Comment: Nope, that you need to do at Module side , but for services is depends.you can use service at module and component both side.